# Styles and Templates at run time WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, mvvm, styles

I have created a custom reusable control in WPF.
I want that while using that, the consumer supplies the styles and templates for the items within the control.
This is not a trivial items control. I am using a third part graph control inside the component I am using. I want that when consuming my control the consumer mentions the styles and templates for nodes/edges. What is the best way to achieve this?

regards,